# What is NSTaggedDate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-composer

I have an error that I can't understand, that is happening while I want to release all objects in an NSMutableDictionary.

It's happening for a custom object called **body** and the output is :

```
-[__NSTaggedDate body]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I found very poor informations about it on the Internet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a private class of Apple. Errors like this usually occur when you mess up your memory management.

Why are you trying to release all objects in a dictionary? When you add an object to a dictionary (or an array), the dictionary will retain it (take ownership). And when you remove the object from the dictionary it will be released, you don't have to do that.

Did you already consider using [ARC](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=arc%20apple&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html&ei=efpRUMWkFebN4QT8hoAQ&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw)? It makes memory management a lot easier. You don't have to worry about retaining and releasing objects anymore.

Comment: Please confer to the comment on the @AliSoftware answer. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Seriously though, what is NSTaggedDate? Are there any practical differences vs NSDate?

Comment: You can get objects that are instances of `__NSTaggedDate` from system frameworks like `ALAssetsLibrary`. Those objects are valid `NSDate` objects as can be seen if checked with `[taggedDate isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]`.

Comment: if (object.class == NSDate.class) { } will not work with a __NSTaggedDate.

Answer (score 6):

It's an internal undocumented cocoa class. But you are not concerned with it as it's not really what's happening, it's a red herring that is probably happening for reasons that are complex to explain and irrelevant here.

Look at the reported address: 0xffffffffffffffff. That's a value that makes no sense. You should have got a segmentation fault, if it was not for that red herring.

You are for some reason sending the message `body` to an invalid pointer (maybe some corrupted data somewhere?).

Answer (score 3):

Don't know this class, but it is probably a private class (my bet would be that it is a internal representation for NSDate objects that use the "tagged pointers" trick, but I'm just guessing).

Anyway your crash is happening not on an *object* called `body`, but when calling a **method** called `body`. And the crash is probably due to bad memory managment in your code that generates memory corruption

- You should activate Zombies when running your app in debug to help you track over-released objects
- You normally don't have to retain and release objects of an `NSDictionary` yourself, as container classes like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` retain the objects they hold, and release them when the object is removed from them. So I don't see why you *"want to release all objects in an NSMutableDictionary"* : you only need to call `removeAllObjects` on that `NSDictionary` and you're done, no need to call `release` on the objects by yourself (neither do you need to call `retain` on the objects when adding them in the dictionary)

Comment: Thank you all. I use this NSMutableDictionary to store references to objects. In Quartz Composer I create objects in one plugin, then pass them to another plugin that stores their references, so they can be used by a third plugin. I'm working on a Quartz Composer port of Box2D and I have to manage my objects and Box2D objects that can't be initialized at the same time. This Dictionary is aimed to keep these references. I release these objects because of the number of retain I use on it, in the different plugins. FYI, I'm using NSZombie.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you try to set one data type to another data type like "if you directly assign an date component to text to an UIlabel" in this case I ll occurs

```
[toDateLabel setText:[tempArr lastObject]];                                   // Cause

[toDateLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempArr lastObject]]]; // Solution
```