# How to make NSDate with associative object work?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to add an associative object to an `NSDate` object. To do this, I use a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279884/how-to-add-userinfo-to-a-uialertview/10319083#10319083).

My problem is now that iOS does not (no longer?) create different NSDate objects for the same date (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885669/copying-an-nsdate-wanting-independent-objects)). Therefore, if I have two items with the same NSDate, I cannot differentiate the objects and my method for adding an associative object for a particular item fails.

I've tried different approaches:

- Using the `copy` method of `NSDate`
- `NSDate *deepCopy = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:date];`
- `NSDate *deepCopy = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];`

But the variables I named `deepCopy` are not deep copies of the original `date` object.

What can I do?

Comment: usually the when NS does tricky stuff you can get a CF plain C version that doesn't do that tricky stuff, or that you can turn off at least... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDateRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFDateRef

Comment: I think that would also be a solution. However, I still hope that someone has another idea that would mean fewer changes in my current project. :-)

Comment: The problem is that the 64-bit runtime uses "tagged pointers" in many cases (where the pointer is not a pointer but contains the information directly). Unfortunately, associated objects do not work with tagged pointers, this was also observed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561211/objc-setassociatedobject-function-error-in-64bit-mode-not-in-32bit.

Comment: @Martin R: Thank you! Now it's definite: I have to change my code.

Comment: Even under the best of circumstances the Objective-C "associative object" mechanism is fragile.  It's best to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about creating a custom model object to represent the combination of the date and whatever other data you want to associate with it? Associated objects should be avoided where possible. Why not subclass `NSObject` to create a model object with two properties - an `NSDate` property and a property/properties for the additional data you want to associate with it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that would be a better way than using associative objects. And I would use this if I cannot make my current approach work. However, it would mean that I'd have to make many changes in my current code...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but this is the result of relying on undocumented behavior (`-copy`)  and edge case solutions (associated objects).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I very much regret that I decided to use associative objects.

Comment: @johnpatrickmorgan: A thought just crossed my mind: Wouldn't it be better to subclass NSDate directly instead of NSObject?

Comment: @vomako I'd say that depends on what information you're associating with the date object, but probably not. If it's not inherently date-related information, then the approach I suggested is likely more appropriate.

Comment: @johnpatrickmorgan: Thank you. I realize that I've never mentioned what I wanted to achieve. :-)  I'm currently associating a variable "allDay" with it.

Comment: NSDate is a class cluster, therefore subclassing it is going to be difficult :)